# Need command-line solution as Brother Printer stops printing unless restarted physically

Tags: macos, printer, hang, lp

I have a shell script code that prints any new PDF generated to a Brother printer which is connected to a MACOS as below

```
lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series /var/pdfs/11.pdf
```

After 2 or 3 days the printer stops to print and I see the printer queue growing with the error message `The printer is not responding`. See Attachment:

[image]

```
tail /var/log/cups/error_log

E [26/Apr/2021:13:38:45 +0200] [Job 15850] The printer is not responding.
E [26/Apr/2021:13:39:45 +0200] [Job 15850] The printer is not responding.

Rustems-iMac:~ rustemince$ lpstat -a
Brother_HL_L2350DW_series accepting requests since Mo 26 Apr 13:24:09 2021
Brother_HL_L2350DW_series_2 accepting requests since Fr  9 Apr 15:28:24 2021
Canon_TS700_series accepting requests since Mo 26 Apr 15:00:32 2021
HP_LaserJet_M203_M206 accepting requests since Sa  3 Apr 09:24:54 2021
HP_LaserJet_M203dw__5F40D6_ accepting requests since Mo 29 Mär 12:26:13 2021
Kyocera_ECOSYS_M5526cdw accepting requests since Di  6 Apr 18:27:08 2021
Kyocera_ECOSYS_M5526cdw_b_3_Fax accepting requests since Di  7 Jan 21:51:33 2020
```

If I manually power off and power on the printer it works and starts the pending prints.

Rather than doing the above manually is there a command line I can use to reset/restart the printer so it can retry the pending queued prints?

Comment: Find out why it stops, first. Look at the logs, `/var/log/*`, or `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u cups`

Comment: @waltinator i already shared `/var/log/cups/error_log` and `-bash: journalctl: command not found`. Rather than debugging can you help with the command line to restart the printer?